# In pint, how do I redefine the micro- symbol to be µ-, not u-?

Tags: python, pint

In [`pint`](http://pint.readthedocs.org/en/0.6/), how do I redefine the `micro-` prefix to be spelt `µ-` rather than `u-`?  Both are aliases when defining units, but when obtaining the short symbol such as with the `{:~}` format specification, `pint` reverts to `u-` even when I try to redefine `micro- = 1e-6 = µ-`:

```
In [155]: ureg.define("micro- = 1e-6 = µ-")
WARNING  2016-01-06 15:19:07,017 unit._adder:563: Redefining 'micro' (<class 'pint.definitions.PrefixDefinition'>)
WARNING  2016-01-06 15:19:07,017 unit._adder:563: Redefining 'µ' (<class 'pint.definitions.PrefixDefinition'>)
```

(Note that these warnings are apparently issued through the logging module and show up due to a rule in my `.pythonrc`, `logging.basicConfig(format=("%(levelname)-8s %(asctime)s %(module)s.%(funcName)s:%(lineno)s: %(message)s"), level=logging.DEBUG)`)

```
In [156]: x = 3 * ureg.micrometre

In [157]: ureg._get_symbol("micrometer")
Out[157]: 'um'

In [158]: "{:~}".format(x)
Out[158]: '3 um'
```

How do I redefine the `micro-` entry in the registry such that `"{:~}".format(x)` will give me `3 µm` rather than `3 um`?

**Edit**

I'm using `pint` from the latest git repository:

```
In [161]: print(pint.__version__)
0.7.dev0
```

**Edit 2**

The situation appears to occur only if there exist previously defined quantities that use the `u-` prefix:

```
In [3]: ureg = pint.UnitRegistry()

In [4]: q = 12 * ureg.um

In [5]: ureg.define("micro- = 1e-6 = µ-")
WARNING  2016-01-06 15:41:25,477 unit._adder:563: Redefining 'micro' (<class 'pint.definitions.PrefixDefinition'>)
WARNING  2016-01-06 15:41:25,477 unit._adder:563: Redefining 'µ' (<class 'pint.definitions.PrefixDefinition'>)

In [6]: x = 3 * ureg.micrometre

In [7]: "{:~}".format(x)
Out[7]: '3 um'
```

But (new session):

```
In [7]: x = 3 * ureg.micrometre

In [8]: "{:~}".format(x)
Out[8]: '3 µm'
```

So I suppose redefining the default needs to be done before using the `u-` alias.

Comment: works fine for me outputs `3 µm` and I also get no warning, what version are you using?

Comment: Huh.  I just restarted `IPython` and now it *does* show `3 µm`.  Something else seems to be going on…  Perhaps some previously defined quantities inhibit `pint` from clearing up the `u-` prefix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to redefine the `µ-` prefix *before* using the (admittedly convenient for somewhat easier to type) `u-` prefix:

```
In [2]: ureg = pint.UnitRegistry()

In [3]: ureg.define("micro- = 1e-6 = µ-")

In [4]: x = 3 * ureg.um

In [5]: print("{:~}".format(x))
3 µm
```

But (other session):

```
In [3]: x = 3 * ureg.um

In [4]: ureg.define("micro- = 1e-6 = µ-")

In [5]: print("{:~}".format(x))
3 um
```